# Posting to multiple campaigns in salesforce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, salesforce

I've created a form to send a lead to salesforce, posting to a certain campaign. Currently it posts to one campaign like so:

`post["Campaign_ID"] = "701D00000001234"`

I need to post to two at once, but whatever i put within that string just seems to get completely ignored..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Lead object in Salesforce there's only one field called `CampaignId` that's a lookup (a foreign key if you prefer) to the Campaigns table.

If you want to link same guy to 2 campaigns you might have to create 2 leads (which is bad idea I think). You can also explore the many-to-many relationship. There's object called `CampaignMember` that lets you link Contacts or Leads to multiple campaigns.

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm for ERD diagram of Campaigns.